# Can I map types when deserializing with "Serde"?

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

Basically I have the following data structure:

```rust
enum Value {
    Scalar(f64),
    Vector3((f64, f64, f64)),
}

struct Data {
    attribute: Value,
}
```

Serializing with [serde](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/index.html)/[serde_json](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/index.html) gives the following

```json
{
    "attribute": { "Scalar": 1.0 }  
}
```

```json
{
    "attribute": { "Vector3": [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ] }
}
```

Deserialize works as intended. However, is it possible to deserialize the following to the same data structure?

```json
{
    "attribute": 1.0  
}
```

```json
{
    "attribute": [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ]
}
```

Is it possible to "map" `f64` to `Scalar(f64)` and `Vec<f64>` to `Vector3((f64, f64, f64))`?

---

Both forms should work. It would be nice if the following minimal example worked:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
```

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
enum Value {
    Scalar(f64),
    Vector3((f64, f64, f64)),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Data {
    attribute: Value,
}

fn main() {
    let js1 = r#"
    {
        "attribute": { "Scalar": 1.0 }  
    }"#;
    let d1: Data = serde_json::from_str(js1).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", d1);

    let js2 = r#"
    {
        "attribute": { "Vector3": [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ] }
    }"#;
    let d2: Data = serde_json::from_str(js2).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", d2);

    let js3 = r#"
    {
        "attribute": 1.0  
    }"#;
    let d3: serde_json::Result<Data> = serde_json::from_str(js3);
    match d3 {
        Ok(d3) => println!("{:?}", d3),
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    }

    let js4 = r#"
    {
        "attribute": [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ] 
    }"#;
    let d4: serde_json::Result<Data> = serde_json::from_str(js4);
    match d4 {
        Ok(d4) => println!("{:?}", d4),
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Data { attribute: Scalar(1.0) }
Data { attribute: Vector3((1.0, 2.0, 3.0)) }
Error("expected value", line: 3, column: 22)
Error("expected value", line: 3, column: 22)
```

Comment: Do you want both forms to work at the same time? Or just the second form?

Comment: @kmdreko Both forms. It would be nice if the minimal example worked. In my particular situation, `Value` contains more than 2 variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Raspberry1111 presented a well-welcomed workaround. However, a more direct solution is still welcome.

---

I had to use `#[serde (untagged)]` (see [Enum representations](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html)) and to change the data structure to meet all of my needs:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
enum TaggedValue {
    Scalar(f64),
    Vector3((f64, f64, f64)),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Value {
    Scalar(f64),
    Vector3((f64, f64, f64)),
    Tagged(TaggedValue),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Data {
    attribute: Value,
}

// [...]
```

Output:

```
Data { attribute: Tagged(Scalar(1.0)) }
Data { attribute: Tagged(Vector3((1.0, 2.0, 3.0))) }
Data { attribute: Scalar(1.0) }
Data { attribute: Vector3((1.0, 2.0, 3.0)) }
```

---

Any more direct solution is still welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#[serde(untagged)]` on your enum to allow it to be "mapped". Serde [doesn't currently support](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1646) both at the same time but there is a [hack here](https://github.com/teloxide/mixed-tags-serde) although I haven't tried it. You could also have an enum with the tagged name inside of the variant

Example:

```rust
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Value {
    Scalar(f64),
    ScalarTagged {Scalar: f64},
    Vector3((f64, f64, f64)),
    Vector3Tagged {
        Vector3: (f64, f64, f64)
    }
}
```

This passes your minimal example

Comment: Your idea inspired my answer.